# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lab_3'

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Написал небольшой графический интерфейс используя библиотеку *PyQt5*.

**app_window.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

...
```

**app_main_window.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from lab_3.gui_6.app_window import Ui_MainWindow
#lab_3.gui_6 - это расположение файла app_window
class myApp (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myApp, self).__init__()
        #Before executin this attribute should be initialized
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
        #self.ui = uic.loadUi('./app_window.ui', self)
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = myApp()
window. show ()
sys.exit (app.exec())
```

При запуске откладки должен был запустится интерфейс, но вместо этого выйдет ошибку :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\...\Pyt\lab_3\gui_6\app_main_window.py", line 3,in <module>
  from lab_3.gui_6.app_window import Ui_MainWindow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lab_3'
```

Кто знает как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что модули **`app_main_window.py`** и **`app_window.py`** лежат в одном каталоге `c:\...\Pyt\lab_3\gui_6\`

а запускаете вы приложение так:

```
python c:\...\Pyt\lab_3\gui_6\app_main_window.py
```

Тогда попробуйте импорт:

```
from app_window import Ui_MainWindow
```

вместо:

```
from lab_3.gui_6.app_window import Ui_MainWindow
```

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо вам

Comment: @doboriyvecer пожалуйста.